# Running PHP IF statement depending on specific HTML select form value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm still new with `PHP` and I'm a bit stumped I'm afraid.

I've searched everywhere and can't quite find a match.

What I'm trying to do is run an `IF` based on the values of an `HTML` select form. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(I'm trying to setup a voting system. I can update the `MySQL` database using different submit buttons but I wish to use a select box instead.)

HTML:

```
<form action='vote_action.php' method='post'>
<select name="selectbox">
<option value=“optone”>optone</option>
<option value=“opttwo”>opttwo</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name="submit" value=’submit’/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['selectbox']))
{
    if(isset($_POST[‘optone’]))
      {
        $vote_optone = "UPDATE mytable SET votes=votes+1 WHERE id=1";

        $run_optone = mysqli_query($con, $vote_optone);

        if($run_optone){

        echo “First updated“; 
                      }
        }


   if(isset($_POST[‘opttwo’]))
      {
        $vote_opttwo = "UPDATE mytable SET votes=votes+1 WHERE id=2”;

        $run_opttwo = mysqli_query($con, $vote_opttwo);

        if($run_opttwo){

        echo “Second updated“; 
                      }
        }


}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Apart from a bit of formatting trouble with smart quotes that seems fine. Checking for errors on your queries might help expose problems, as you're not doing that.

Comment: Check `selectbox` not `opttwo`; `opttwo` is the value, not the name.

Comment: It's not updating the database when I run it or displaying the echo. Say I select 'optone' from the dropdown; I just get a blank page. When I add an echo at the bottom it will show and if I put my SQL in 'selectbox' it runs. I know the form is sending the value because it appears when I echo it. Stumped!

Comment: Did you fix all the quotes/backticks? Did you check your error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (isset($_POST[‘optone’])) {
    // ...
}
```

to

```
if ($_POST['selectbox'] == 'optone')) {
    // ...
}
```

and do the same for `opttwo`.

Note that strings in PHP are quoted with `'` or `"`, not with `‘`.

Comment: Many thanks Oscar! I've got 'optone' working now but when 'opttwo' is selected it still runs optone. Can you help?

Comment: Ignore my last comment! Got it working. Many thanks again!

Comment: Can I add selected without using if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['selectbox']  === 'optone')
```

optone and opttwo are values

Answer (score -1):

Is'nt this a better solution?

```
<form action="vote_action.php" method="post">
    <select name="selectbox">
        <option value="1">optone</option>
        <option value="2">opttwo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['selectbox'])) {

$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mytable SET votes=votes+1 WHERE id=".$_POST['selectbox']."");

    if($query){
        echo "Updated"; 
    }

}
```

**Note: This is vunerable for SQL injection!**

**EDIT: Updated against users that are not doing what you want ;)**

```
$allowed_ids = array(1, 2);

if(isset($_POST['selectbox']) && in_array($_POST['selectbox'], $allowed_ids)) {

$selected = bin2hex($_POST['selectbox']);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mytable SET votes=votes+1 WHERE id=UNHEX('$selected')");

    if($query){
        echo "Updated"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Two problems with this. Firstly, as you already mentioned, the SQL injection vulnerability. Secondly, a malicious user can easily submit integer values other than `0` or `1`, which might change some other row in that table. However, you could mitigate both issues effectively by using `"UPDATE mytable ... WHERE id=".((int) (bool) $_POST['selectbox'])` instead. I would still advise against this solution nonetheless, as you might very well have other `id`'s than `0` and `1` in the future.

Comment: So if i already mentioned you don't have to mention again right? And a malicious user input can be solved with an easy solution: Set all the allowed ID's in a array. Check if it exist and voila. User input should always be validated. Not my task and not where the questioner is asking for. But for this time, i will update my code in a second

Comment: lol why the downvote ?! Its a correct answer what does what the questioner asked for ?

Comment: I voted you down because although your answer solves the questioner's problem with the if-statement, it also introduces a _new_ security hole. The original code of the questioner might have been incorrect, but at least it was secure. Your edit doesn't have that problem of course, but rather than adding it at the bottom, you should have just replaced your original answer out. I also don't see the point of calling `bin2hex` and `UNHEX` when you can just cast the variable to integer type, and in fact it is interpreted as such by the MySQL server anyway if you drop the quotes around `$selected`.

Comment: What? This is ridiculus... I helped him even more because its better to see how i changed my code to improve security. And do you know the purpose of hexing usage the way i did? Its against SQL injection and its 100% secure

Comment: Please don't take it personal that I don't like your answer. I can see how hexing protects against SQL injection. However, since your `in_array` condition already does that, it is rather redundant in this case.

Comment: The point is: Is my answer usefull? If yes, then upvote, if no, then downvote. And the answer is usefull in fact, so not liking it is a total different case and thus not fair to downvote for. But now he does got 2 ways to prevent his code.

Comment: My vote is my own, nothing unfair about that. If it is such a big deal to you... remove the insecure code from your answer, as I suggested earlier, and I will change my vote.